# Is order maintained when going from tuple to list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm pretty sure this is the case but I couldn't find any documentation about it: If I have a tuple `my_tuple` and create a list from it `my_list = list(my_tuple)` can I be sure that the order is preserved?

Comment: yes , it does `[x for x in my_tuple]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `list` is populated in the order that the iterable provides, this is clearly [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list):

> The constructor builds a list whose items are the same and in the same
> order as iterable’s items.

And `tuple` object are ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The `list` constructor iterates over its argument in order. So `a = list(b)` is equivalent to:

```
a = []
for item in b:
    a.append(item)
```

... and iterating over a tuple yields each of its elements in order. So order is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

A tuple is a collection of objects which are ordered and immutable. Tuples are sequences, just like lists. The differences between tuples and lists are, the tuples cannot be changed unlike lists and tuples use parentheses, whereas lists use square brackets.

So the data copied between the list and tuple will always maintain the same order.

Documentation for python tuple can be found at below link,

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm